# Updating list of lists at iteration

Tags: python

I've a list of lists and I want to update each list at iteration.
I initialized my list as follows:

```
my_list = [[0]*n]*n
```

When I want to update the inner lists, by something like:

```
for i in range(something):
    for j in range(anotherthing):
        my_list[i][j] = something
```

What happens is that the whole list is updated rather than the ith list only at each iteration, e.g. [[1,2], [1,2]]. 
What I want is at the first iteration to be [[1,2], [0,0]] as I initialized it, and in to be [[1,2], [values]]. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list multiplication operator `*` does not create copies, but creates multiple references to the same data. Instead of using `*` consider using comprehensions for initializing your list:

```
my_list = [[0 for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to initialize your list of lists and it will work fine.

```
x = [[0]*n for i in range(n)]
```

The original code creates a list of sublists too but every single one of the sublists reference the same object.

Note: I am using Python3. If you are using 2, you might need to use xrange() instead of range().